# Validating text input - bug in implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I've encountered a user interface issue with validation I really want to solve. For the website: http://fun-booths.co.uk/dev/

I'm using this simple plugin for validation: http://www.formvalidator.net/

The simple code behind this is as follows:

```
 $.validate({
      form : '#fscf_form1, #fscf_form2',
      validateOnBlur : true, 
      scrollToTopOnError : false 
    });
```

The `validateOnBlur` property makes sure validation occurs when inputs loose focus.

There is a form in the right hand sidebar. When selecting a date and time the validation is not functioning correctly.

Fill out the town/city and postcode fields with the correct test data format for example. You will notice a green tick dynamically appear. Now for the date and time fields an end user does not actually type, the input is given to the form field by clicking on the responsive time picker / date picker respectively.

After selecting a date and time and focusing on other input elements this results in the following issue (even though  a value has been selected a red cross is presented in the form field which is not desired behaviour.):

[image]

I believe this issue is stemming from the fact that the user does not actually enter text into the time or date fields. So the validation does not detect that actual text has been entered into the form.

**Note**: A strange behaviour is that a green tick does appear on the date/time fields if a value is chosen, then the same input is selected/given focus again.

Is there a JavaScript/jQuery solution that could fire with an event listener to solve this issue and ensure a green tick appears? Or would textual input need to physically be typed in to the date/time fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hack, should work :

```
$('.picker__input').on('change', function(){
    $(this).focus();
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please can I ask what $(this) refers to in this context? I am writing up a description of this code snippet for learning purposes. Am I correct in saying that $(this) refers to the specific .picker__input that had a change event occur at that specific moment? In other words isn't the purpose of $(this) in this case to be used as a form of placeholder thay dynamically selects the specific .picker__input that was interacted with?

Comment: Your help/clarification will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @user1554264, `$(this)` refer to the element that has class `picker__input`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two plugins to work together. Try to give a callback to pickadate asking to reprocess the field:

```
$('#fscf_field2_12').pickadate({
   //... add this parameter
   onClose: function() {
      $('#fscf_field2_12').blur();
   },
   //... or this one
   onSet: function() {
      $('#fscf_field2_12').blur()
   }  
})
```

You can also check the [validateOnEvent](https://github.com/victorjonsson/jQuery-Form-Validator#validate-on-event) method from jQuery-Form-Validator.